# How to: Tex fonts

Tags: fonts

I want to learn something about how TeX fonts works.

- But I don't know where to start?
- Is there any book about it?
- Where I can find some library of the TeX fonts? (with preview)

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about what you mean by "how TeX fonts work". "TeX fonts" is a rather large topic. If in doubt, start with the TeXbook.

Answer (score 4):

The "original" `tex` fonts were "written" in an (other) language invented by knuth, called `metafont`.  A `metafont` program describes the shape of each *glyph* of a font, together with general properties of the font.  The *program* `metafont` translates a font described in the language, and assembles it (with help from other utilities) into something that can be used by `tex`.  A (plain) `tex` document can "just" use such a font.

While Knuth was developing metafont, Adobe was selling fonts, and developing a structure for them.  Eventually, this format was published as "Adobe Type 1" format.  So tex experts developed utilities for making adobe's fonts available to tex users.  A (plain) `tex` document can "just" use such a font, with those ancillary utilities.

And then Adobe, with other companies, developed TrueType and OpenType formats for more advanced use (e.g., multiple alphabets in the same font).  A plain `tex` document simply cannot use such fonts, but modern tex variants (primarily xetex and luatex) can.

SO ... what else do you want to know?

references: [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org) -- several of the early answers deal with fonts.

Comment: This is confused, I think. `plain` is a format. You can use ttf/otf with this format. What matters is the engine - not the format. The TeX engine can't use them. pdfTeX can use ttf, at least.

Comment: Also, TeX cannot use type1 fonts directly, any more than pdfTeX or the other engines. Just as pdfTeX can't use ttf directly. In fact, the TeX engine (as opposed to pdfTeX) has nothing to do with the type1 fonts as supplied by Adobe. It just uses the TFMs etc. You need something else to actually use the PFB/PFA parts. (Of course, the TFMs etc. are partly from the AFMs, but they have nothing of the PFB/PFAs.) That depends on the DVI viewer or postprocessor.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a list of the available TeX fonts on the [Comprehensive TeX Archive Network](http://ctan.org/topic/font) and another list with demonstrations and sample code at [the Danish TeX Users Group website](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue).

Answer (score 0):

See the below link for a Latex font catalogue:
http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/